# How to define a heavy object in Matter JS

Tags: javascript, matter.js

To explain better what I need, think about a tank and a can of soda.
No matter what the speed of that can of soda would be, the tank wouldn't move if it's hit.
But the tank should be able to move when force is applied to it.

Already opened an issue here with more details:
https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/841

And I also made an example here for what I need.

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
  Render = Matter.Render,
  World = Matter.World,
  Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
  Body = Matter.Body;

var engine = Engine.create();
engine.positionIterations = 10;
engine.velocityIterations = 8;

var render = Render.create({
  element: document.body,
  engine: engine,
  options: {
    width: 800,
    height: 400,
    wireframes: false
  }
});

engine.world.gravity.y = 0;

var topWall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 50, 720, 20, { isStatic: true });
var leftWall = Bodies.rectangle(50, 210, 20, 300, { isStatic: true });
var rightWall = Bodies.rectangle(750, 210, 20, 300, { isStatic: true });
var bottomWall = Bodies.rectangle(400, 350, 720, 20, { isStatic: true });

var ball = Bodies.circle(100, 200, 5, { 
  friction: 0.05,
  frictionAir: 0.05,
  density: 0.001,
  restitution: 0.2
});

var bigBox = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(500, 200, 120, 120, {
  inertia: Infinity,
  frictionAir: 1,
  friction: 1,
  density: 0.1
});

World.add(engine.world, [topWall, leftWall, rightWall, bottomWall, ball, bigBox]);
Engine.run(engine);
Render.run(render);

// CMD + SHIFT + 7 to reload

$('.shoot').on('click', function () {
  var speed = 0.02;
  var angle = 0;
  let vector = Matter.Vector.create(Math.cos(angle) * speed, Math.sin(angle) * speed);
  Body.applyForce(ball, ball.position, vector);
});
```

https://codepen.io/dmerlea/pen/BaoQJYK

Comment: I've managed to find a temporary solution: making the ball a sensor. since I only need the collision, but not any movement

Comment: To use your analogy, there's no floor for the tank to sit on, and no gravity to pull the tank onto the floor. The static friction would be the property you could make use of if that were the case. I think in this case you'll just want to set a really high density for the tank, and a low density for the bullet. Can't get around conservation of momentum!    That said, I'm guessing you tried this sort of an approach and it didn't work out?

Comment: See also [Matter JS - Physics - How to define a heavy element, hard to be moved by small ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876440/matter-js-physics-how-to-define-a-heavy-element-hard-to-be-moved-by-small-o)

Comment: Tangential: don't underestimate forces generated by fast objects consisting largely of incompressible matter.